# react native search bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uisearchbar, react-native-ios

I am trying to make a search bar with buttons on the left and right of the search, in react native. I've had no luck with being able to customize my search bar to do this. I tried to do it, the same way you would add something to the left and right of a header, but I'm not sure if I can use leftComponent and rightComponent with searchbar. Any tips?

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{ marginTop:110 }}>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.searchBar.show()}>
               </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
                <SearchBar
                ref='searchBar'
                searchBarStyle="default"
                placeholder='Search local'
                leftComponent={<MyLeftComponent />}
                rightComponent={<MyRightComponent />}
                />                 
            <Content contentContainerStyle={{
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'

            }}>
                <Text>Your Profile!</Text>
            </Content>
         </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: You can use the native ios search bar - https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar

Comment: But how can I add buttons to the left and right of it?